# An OR power supply circuit

Tags: power, digital-logic, diodes, switches

consider the following circuit:

[image]

This image shows a simple "diode OR" power supply switch. I am trying to derive the cheapest circuit to obtain this functionality (the given circuit does not fulfil the requirements):

1. Assume VCC2 = 5 V, VCC1 = 3.3 V.
2. When VCC2 is present and VCC1 is not present, the LOAD is supplied with voltage equal to VCC2.
3. When VCC1 is present and VCC2 is not present, the LOAD is supplied with voltage equal to VCC1.
4. When VCC1 is present and VCC2 is present, the LOAD is supplied with voltage equal to VCC1.
5. Current cannot flow from VCC1 to VCC2 or vice versa.

I would appreciate all ideas!

Comment: Clearly, you need active logic for this. But I wonder whether you might be better served by changing some parts of the system architecture to use the same voltage for both inputs?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/primer-on-powerpath-controllers-ideal-diodes-prioritizers.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes, I thought about adding an 3.3V LDO behind VCC2, which would make the case easier, but was not sure whether thats the cheapest option I have.

Comment: Thanks for the link Peter. I thought about ideal diodes, but these are quite expensive...

Comment: You need to clarify **exactly** why the diode solution does not meet your needs. Also, quantify what you mean by "equal to" for these voltages. If you mean exactly the same then you are probably out of luck, so give us some numbers.

Comment: Hi, the circuit would not work, because when both voltages are present, the load will be near 5 V (ignoring the diode forward voltage drops), instead of 3.3 V. When saying equal, I mean very close to.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could do it with a SPST (or SPDT) relay IF you can tolerate having 3.3V appear momentarily at the 5V output.  If not, you'll have to put in a diode on the 5V supply but remember that it will drop 0.7V.

Edit: on closer inspection you'll need D1 to prevent the 5V supply from powering up RLY1's coil.  This also prevents the 5V supply from shorting into the 3.3V supply, but you still have the diode voltage drop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZaoPB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>